# How to create terrain files with points in Cesium?

Tags: cesiumjs, terrain

I have a DEM file with XYZ points ([file sample image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZCd9.png), and I want to use it to create terrain in Cesium with it. I tried to translate it to GeoTiff by ArcMap, but it is not supported by cesium terrain builder.

How could I create terrain files with points in Cesium?

Answer (score 1):

Cesium is able to consume [Quantized Mesh tiles](https://github.com/CesiumGS/quantized-mesh) but not `GTIFF` or `XYZ` directly.

First, you will have to convert your `XYZ` file to e.g. `GTIFF` and transform it to WGS84 coordinate reference system. Both can be done using [gdal](https://gdal.org/).

Second, convert your transformed `GTIFF` files to `quantized-mesh` format.

I created a Docker image for that purpose. Check out the Github page of [tumgis/cesium-terrain-builder-docker](https://github.com/tum-gis/cesium-terrain-builder-docker) for a detailed documentation of the entire process.

Finally, you will need a service like [CesiumTerrainServer](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-server) to serve the tiles to a Cesium application.